# Particle JS - How to add Multiple Images as a particle

Tags: particles.js

Is there a way to add multiple images in particle js?
I Searched for the solution but cant find anything working.

Here is my particle.json settings.

```
      "shape": {
        "type": "image",
        "stroke":{
        "width": 2,
        "color": "#a80cc0"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "./assets/images/gift.png",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at the particlesjs sources and I think that there is no such possibility. 
Although it should work with React component: https://github.com/Wufe/react-particles-js

But as workaround you could use several particlejs instances with different images.

See this issue https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/324

Then it may look like this: https://github.com/Dubprocessor/multiple-particlesjs-instances-example/tree/master

Consider that a large number of instances will affect performance.